# Using ASP.NET MVC how do I create a link for subscribing to an iCal from Outlook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outlook, icalendar

I have a calendar in my ASP.NET MVC site that I want to publish so that it can be subscribed to by an Microsoft Outlook client.  How can I accomplish this without manually specifying the whole url (for example using `Url.Action`)?  The format should be:

`webcals://mywebsite.com/ProjectDate/MyDates`

Note - I'm using `https` so the webcal protocol is `webcals`.  If I were using standard `http` then the protocol would be `webcal`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Url.Action` method has a "protocol" parameter that you can use to specify "webcals" as the protocol.  Here is an example:

`<a href="@Url.Action("MyDates", "ProjectDate", null, "webcals")">`